# entity - Removing ".dbo" from table name in Entity Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Code First in a project, and I want to make my tables have names different from the models.

I tried to use the DataAnnotation `Table` in the model class:

```
[Table("tbBudget")]
public class Budget : IValidatableObject
{
...
```

But the table created is named `dbo.tbBudget`. The question is simple: how do I remove the `dbo.` from the table name in Entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables in database always belong to schema. You can not remove schema, but you can change it with fluent configuration, overriding method in DbContext

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Budget>().ToTable("test", "mySchema");
    }
```

Or, as in your example, you can use [TableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx)

Comment: And you can also specify it in the Table attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx. Please, edit your answer

Answer (score 4):

The *dbo.* is not part of the actual table name but denotes the schema name.